# how to use HttpDelete in android

Tags: android

i want to delete some thing from android phone in server through API. i am new. How to use the HTTPDELETE in android.
the url is something like this.
               http://api.someApi.net/v1/medium/6.

Comment: you're using apache http client or UrlConnection ? in both cases you're should be able to set http method

Comment: just use HttpDelete like you would a Get